# Import errors inspite of mentioning rules in .eslintrc.js

Tags: typescript, eslint

This is my .eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  extends: ['airbnb', 'eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  rules: {
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
      },
    ],

    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 'off',

    'react/destructuring-assignment': 'off',
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      1,
      { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.tsx'] },
    ],
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
  },
  settings: {
    'import/extensions': ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    },
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
};
```

I'm running `yarn start` and I still see errors like "Missing file extension "tsx" for ".header/SiteHeader" and "JSX not allowed in files with extension '.tsx'".

What am I doing incorrectly? I just followed answers from other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: How do you think the linting configuration relates to what happens when you run yarn start?

Comment: Oh, sorry if that's not the case. I'm new to Typescript/React and when I try to run my project on localhost I see an error - https://share.getcloudapp.com/L1upDWBK

Comment: It seems like whenever I edit my .eslintrc file I have to delete the eslint cache to reflect the changes